# How to make an executable file appear in search

Tags: 13.10, executable

I've downloaded a program and in order to run it I open terminal, cd into the directory it's stored in and run it by typing `./<program>`. This is a bit of a hassle as I use this program on a daily basis. How do I set it so that I can find the program by typing the name of the program (TeamSpeak) into search when I press the super key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your program show up in the Unity Dash (pressing the Super key), it needs a launcher (.desktop) file in the proper place.

So create a file named **TeamSpeak.desktop** in the directory **~/.local/share/applications** containing the following:

> [Desktop Entry]
>   Name=TeamSpeak
>   Comment=Voice communications system for games
>   Exec=/full/path/to/program
>   Terminal=false
>   Type=Application

After you do that, it should show up in the Dash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the program to the PATH. Go to your home directory. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, you can now see hidden files. Open `.bashrc` in your favourite text editor and add this to the end of the file (changing the directory to the correct one):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/directory/of/program"
```

Save and exit.

Open the terminal and run:

```
source .bashrc
```

Now try running your program.

Comment: Shouldn't that be export PATH?

Comment: Good catch! Updated. Just seen that you wanted to launch from pressing super! So I was a little irrelevant anyway. Sorry, perhaps would be good to have that at the start of the question?